# erased HD, did clean install, no iLife -- can I get iLife off from MacBook DVD?

Tags: macos, ilife

My MacBook came with Snow Leopard installed and it came with "recovery" DVDs, I upgraded to Lion via the App Store.  I had a problem with my MacBook -- the Apple Genius concluded I needed to do a full clean reinstall of Lion.

I erased the HD and reinstalled Lion. Everything's good now, except I don't have the iLife apps.

How do I get iLife?

For example, can I get the iLife apps off of the (Snow Leopard) DVDs that came with my MacBook?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For pre-mid-2011 machines, yes, the recovery DVD is the way to reinstall iLife. For machines that ship with Lion, your account at the App Store should be credited with the iLife programs in the Purchased tab; go there, sign in, and you can redownload them.

Comment: I discovered that the second DVD that came with my "Snow Leopard" MacBook had an installer on it to "install bundled applications". I ran this and got iLife back.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get them back with out repurchasing them from the MAS, what you could have done is do a clean reinstall from your Snow Leopard recovery dvd, and then re-install Lion on top of that.

iLife does not come with the operating system, it comes with the computer, so by wiping it clean and only re-installing Lion, you miss out.

You can either start over with Snow Leopard or purchase them again from the MAS.

Comment: You can install iLife off of the restore DVD without reinstalling the operating system.